# What is the syntax for a SQL UPDATE when the new value is a local variable

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

In a C# Windows program, I want to update a Int field in a SQL Server table

```
int NewSeqno = MySeqno;    // get current sequence number

NewSeqno++;     // increment it

connection.Open();

// The following errors out saying that NewSeqno is not a column in the table.

// I want to update the field with the local variable NewSeqno.

command.CommandText = "UPDATE dbo.params SET NextSeqno = NewSeqno";

int recordsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

// The following statement, which writes a constant in the field, works fine.
command.CommandText = "UPDATE dbo.params SET NextSeqno = 123";
```

Comment: You should learn how to do [parameterized queries in C#](http://bobby-tables.com/csharp) and [why they're necessary](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: [You add a parameter to your `UPDATE` statement and then you bind your variable to that parameter.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) That link to MSDN has, as it's example, an UPDATE statement.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the parameter to SQL query

update the command text as below -

```
command.CommandText = "UPDATE dbo.params SET NextSeqno = @NewSeqno";
```

Add this line to pass parameter

```
command.Parameters.Add("@NewSeqno", SqlDbType.Int).Value = NewSeqno;
```

Comment: [You should avoid using `AddWithValue`.](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: agree, updated my answer.